# How can I set the focus for a DevExpress XtraGrid so the mouse wheel works right away?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

The UI for my WinForms app is centered around a DevExpress XtraGrid.

Usually, the first thing a user wants to do is scroll the grid, so the normal instinct is to move the mouse wheel.

But currently, you have to click a row in the grid first, which is annoying.

I tried to use BaseView.Focus method, but this did not work - still had to click a row before the wheel would work.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Grid is scrolled by mouse wheel only if the mouse pointer is above the grid. So, an attempt to focus it does not help.  To change this behavior, you should change the  static SmartMouseWheelProcessing property in the form's constructor as shown below:

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.MouseWheelHelper.SmartMouseWheelProcessing = false;
```

Comment: I tried adding the above to the form's constructor, and in addition, added a call to the GridView's Focus method in the form's Load event, but I still have to click the GridView before the wheel will work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Tom, focus the grid within the form's Shown event handler.  Load is too early.

Comment: Adding gridView.Focus() to the form's Shown handler worked - thanks!  Did not need to set SmartMouseWheelProcessing after all.

Comment: I cannot find `MouseWheelHelper.SmartMouseWheelProcessing` under `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing` namespace...